# Error while trying feed a class parameter in php

Tags: php, class

i declared classes like this:

```
class Foo{ public function __construct(){ echo 'Foo was created!';} }

class Foo2 extends Foo{ public function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); echo 'Foo2 was created!';} }

class Bar{
    public function __construct(Foo $foo){ echo 'Bar was created!';}
}
```

in main code:

```
$foo2 = new Foo2();
$bar = new Bar($foo2);
```

What is reason of this error in main code:

```
Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL
```

php version: PHP 5.3.2

--------------------------------------Updated!----------------------------------------

file: system.data.php

```
namespace system\data{

    include ('system.php');

    use system;    
class DBConnection implements system\IDisposable {
    protected $serverName;
    protected $userId;
    protected $password;
    protected $handler;
    protected $isOpened;

    /*
     * create a new instance of DBConnection.
    */
    public function __construct($server, $uid, $password) {
        $this->isOpened = false;
        $this->serverName = $server;
        $this->userId = $uid;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
class DBCommand implements \system\IDisposable {

    public function  __construct(DBConnection $connection, int $type) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->queryType= $type;
}
```

}

file: system.data.mysql.php

```
namespace system\data\mysql{
    class MySqlCommand extends DBCommand {

        public function __construct(data\DBConnection $connection, int $type = 0) {
            parent::__construct($connection, $type);
        }
    }

class MySqlConnection extends DBConnection {

    public function  __construct($server, $uid, $password) {
        parent::__construct($server, $uid, $password);
        }

    }
}
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\...\system.data.mysql.php on line 35(constructor declartion)
```

Comment: That code gives me no errors.

Comment: Works for me. What is the line number that the error message reports, and does your `Bar` constructor really correspond to that line?

Comment: The main code of project is long! but i'm sure that pattern is like that! when and why did this error happening?

Comment: Still works fine for me even after your edit. How about showing the real code and the full error message?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the main code of the project is long, because 1) the error only refers to one line of code 2) the error does not happen in your main code, but in the problematic method/constructor.

Comment: Furthermore, the error message itself *only* happens when the default value for a type-hinted paramater is present and not null.  Your code above does not meet the criteria to cause the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the full code, here's your error:

```
public function __construct(data\DBConnection $connection, int $type = 0)
```

**PHP 5.3 only supports type hinting for arrays and classes.**

Your declaration of `int $type = 0` is looking for a *class* named "int", and parses it as such, even if the class doesn't exist.

You'll need to remove the bogus type hint.  The PHP developers are [considering adding other type hints in the future](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/typechecking).  There's [currently code in PHP's trunk](http://ilia.ws/archives/217-Scalar-Type-Hints-are-Here!.html) to perform type hinting for scalar values, but much has changed since that blog article was posted.  I'll see if I can track down the current state of things, but searching the PHP internals mailing list is a dreadfully horrible task.

---

Edit: After digging through PHP Internals, I found [the latest Type Hinting](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg46503.html) thread.  It looks like [this the current Type Hinting RFC](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/typecheckingstrictandweak), but there doesn't appear to be consensus on the direction.  Zeev wanted to rollback the commit, but it's not clear if that was done.